# Is it possible to override C++11 lambda/closure destructor?

Tags: c++11, lambda, destructor, c++14, coroutine

I am playing with C++11 lambda/closure feature, trying to write a semi-coroutine (generator) function.

The following codes are my experiment. They works as expected (GCC 4.9/Linux).

I have read several on-line articles introducing C++ lambda/closure, now I understand the lambda function as a functor or function object.

My question is: where can I put the destructor code for closure object? how can I override the default destructor?

I need this function because, some coroutines may request certain system resources when I call the function constructing and returning the closure object (which represents a coroutine). But if the caller function decide to cancel / kill the operation, there should be a mechanism to inform the coroutine object to take some action. The ideal place to put code will be in the destructor, but I cannot find how.

Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <time.h>

#define CONCAT01(a, b)                      a##b
#define CONCAT02(a, b)                      CONCAT01(a, b)
#define YIELD()                             \
  do {                                      \
    CONCAT02(ENTRY, __LINE__):              \
    if (EP == && CONCAT02(ENTRY, __LINE__)) \
      EP = 0;                               \
    else                                    \
    {                                       \
      EP = && CONCAT02(ENTRY, __LINE__);    \
      return true;                          \
    }                                       \
  } while (0)

using namespace std;

typedef std::function<bool(void)> coroutine;

coroutine add(int a, int b, int * ret)
{
  timespec start;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

  return [=]() mutable -> bool
  {
    timespec now;
    while(1) {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
      if (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec > 1)
        break;

      return true;
    }
    * ret = a + b;
    cout << "add " << a << " " << b << " equals: " << a + b << endl;
    return false;
  };
}

coroutine sum(int a, int b, int c, int * ret)
{
  void* EP = 0;
  coroutine co = 0;
  int tmp = 0;

  return [=] () mutable -> bool
  {
    if (EP) goto *EP;

    co = add(a, b, &tmp);
    while(co())
      YIELD();

    co = add(tmp, c, ret);
    while(co())
      YIELD();

    return false;
  };
}

int main()
{
  int ret;
  coroutine c = sum(1, 2, 4, &ret);
  while (c())
    {
      sleep(1);
      cout << "wakeup" << endl;
    }

  cout << "final: " << ret << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++11 but not C++14?  You do know that by using `std::function` you are asserting that your coroutines can be copied?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "coroutines can be copied". The above code works and that is exactly how we will use this pattern in real world code. We don't intend to copy a coroutine object from one place to another.

Comment: a `std::function<bool()>` is an object that is type-erased down to being invoked with `()` returning a type compatible with `bool` and can be copied.  Both are required by `std::function`, and the type provides that guarantees to its consumers.  If you don't intend to promise both, possibly you shouldn't use it.

Comment: @Yakk, I admit that a copyable coroutine is something sounds weird. But other than std::function<bool()>, is there any other way to get a handle to closure object? I use lambda/closure partly because it can capture the argument variable automatically, i can also put persistent states in containing function which will be copied to closure member automatically. In this way, the code looks simple. Otherwise I must hand code a constructor, which is inconvenient.

Comment: @Yakk, actually I am using this pattern on microcontroller, to replace the while-loop state machine pattern or message/event dispatching pattern, which are very awkward and unnatural for complex controll flow. All so-called coroutine function is a small state machine. The sub function is sub state machine. A "Call stack" can be viewed as a thread. Up to now, my code works flawlessly. They all looks like the code presented above. But I don't know is it a dangerous practice, could you point out in what situation, such 'copyable' feature would easily get things messy?

Comment: @matainfu do you have C++14?

Comment: @Yakk, probably yes, I use gcc arm cross-compiler, version 4.9. the doc says it supports c++14. Suggestion?

Comment: Replace `coroutine` with `auto` everywhere, for one.  Needless type erasure means memory allocation and indirection costs.  I'd also replace the `void*EP=0;` in the corroutine-returning funcion with `[=,EP=(void*)0]` in the lambda argument list (possibly making it a macro, as well as the `if(EP) goto*EP;` line as a macro).  On the subject in question... can you include sample code for what kind of operation you want to perform on an abort?  Is it different than the kind of code you'd want to perform after the coroutine finishes?  Have you looked at the MSVC 2015 coroutine support?

Comment: (The MSVC thing -- I'm talking about as a source of design inspiration.  Its coroutines return data, instead of returning true/false).

Comment: @Yakk, thank you so much for you suggestions. For cancelling a coroutine, it is mostly happened when a high level state machine (also a coroutine) observes a (polling) state change or receives a message; then it decides to destroy the current sub state machine and start another one.

Comment: @Yakk, for example, in usb core driver, when the usb device disconnected, the core should cancel all blocking operations, the yielded enumeration coroutine (a sub stm), and control pipe operation (sub sub stm), and usb_submit_urb operation (sub sub sub stm). This is a typical case in microcontroller. Well, if it's hard to do so, another choice is to design the usb core as a observer. It's lower layer, the host controller device (hcd) layer can handle disconnect event itself.

Comment: @Yakk, If I do not use the lambda/closure, and use a normal class/object instead. I prefer to write the cancelling logic in destructor. There are cases you should do so. For example, you started a hardware timer or a ADC sampling, you should stop it before the state machine exit. Operation should always be in pair, unless the hardware goes berserkly and requires a reset.

Comment: Beware that the computed goto is a GCC extension and completely non-portable.  According to the C++ Standard the code is ill-formed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an object with a task and a destroy task:

```
template<class F, class D>
struct coroutine {
  F f;
  D d;
  template<class...Args>
  std::result_of_t<F&(Args...)>
  operator()(Args&&...args){
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ~coroutine() {
    d();
  }
};
```

a factory function for it:

```
template<class F, class D>
coroutine< std::decay_t<F>, std::decay_t<D> >
make_coroutine( F&& f, D&& d ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<D>(d)};
}
```

Some helper macros:

```
#define COROUTINE_STATE ED=(void*)0
#define START_COROUTINE if (ED) goto *ED
#define FINISH_COROUTINE return false

auto add(int a, int b, int * ret) {
  timespec start;
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

  return make_coroutine([=]() mutable
  {
    timespec now;
    while(true) {
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
      if (now.tv_sec - start.tv_sec > 1)
        break;

      return true;
    }
    *ret = a + b;
    cout << "add " << a << " " << b << " equals: " << a + b << endl;
    return false;
  },
  []{
    cout << "adder destroyed\n";
  });
}
auto sum(int a, int b, int c, int * ret)
{
  std::function<bool()> co;
  int tmp = 0;

  return make_coroutine([=,COROUTINE_STATE] () mutable
    {
      START_COROUTINE;
      co = add(a, b, &tmp);
      while(co())
        YIELD();

      co = add(tmp, c, ret);
      while(co())
        YIELD();

      FINISH_COROUTINE;
    },
    []{
      std::cout << "winter is coming\n";
    }
  );
}
```

note that in this design, the destructor does not have access to any state changes in the "body", like `ED`.

You capture `COROUTINE_STATE` to get the `ED` pointer.  Then you `START_COROUTINE;` to do the auto-branch, `YIELD()` to insert a jump spot, and `FINISH_COROUTINE;` to end the coroutine.

The lack of shared state is a serious problem here.  The `co` the body has access to is completely different than the `co` the destroyer would have access to if it did a `=`.

We could get around this by adding a new state to your coroutine that happens "after" the `FINISH_COROUTINE;` or somesuch.  Injecting the ability to access that is tricky -- one approach would be to move `ED` out of the lambda capture itself:

```
template<class F>
struct coroutine {
  void** ED = nullptr;
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  std::result_of_t< F&(void**,Args...) >
  operator()(Args&&...args){
    return f(ED, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
  ~coroutine() {
    void* end = 0;
    f(&end);
  }
};
template<class F>
coroutine<std::decay_t<F>>
make_coroutine(F&& f){return {std::forward<F>{f}};}
#define START_COROUTINE [=](void** ED)mutable{\
  if (ED){if (*ED)goto *ED;\
  else goto Cleanup;}
#define END_COROUTINE_BODY return false; Cleanup:
#define END_COROUTINE_CLEANUP }
#define END_COROUTINE END_COROUTINE_BODY; END_COROUTINE_CLEANUP

auto sum(int a, int b, int c, int * ret)
{
  std::function<bool()> co = 0;
  int tmp = 0;

  return
  START_COROUTINE
    co = add(a, b, &tmp);
    while(co())
      YIELD();

    co = add(tmp, c, ret);
    while(co())
      YIELD();
  END_COROUTINE_BODY
    std::cout << "winter is coming\n";
  END_COROUTINE_CLEANUP;
}
```

or something like that.  We pass the `ED` explicitly, and if it is pointing to a nullptr we take that to mean "jump to the cleanup code".  This place the cleanup code in the same scope as the body.

I see now where your type erasure down to `std::function` might be useful.  Note that such type erasure requires memory allocation overhead (in practice), which is unfortunate, and virtual function overhead on each call.

Sadly, I reused your `coroutine` typename before I figured that out, so started using `std::function<bool()` directly.  My apologies.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I need some time to figure it out. I haven't use C++ template for years. It may take me quite some time to recover.

Comment: @matianfu note that I did not compile the above code, so sadly it could contain many typos and errors.